# ReactDom is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just starting to learn react and I am trying this code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const element = <h1>Hello world</h1>;
console.log(element);
```

But I have error :

> ReactDom is declared but its value is never read
> [image]
> what may cause this error please ?

Comment: What causes the error is exactly what is described - `ReactDom` is declared (by the import) but its value is never read (you never actually _use_ it).

Answer (score 0):

On line two you declare `ReactDom` (and assign (i.e. *write*) the imported value from the react-dom module to it).

> ```
> import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
> ```

… and then **you never do anything with it** (i.e. you don't read the value back out of the `ReactDom` variable).

Normally in a React application you would use `ReactDom` to insert a component into the DOM, but here you just `console.log` the result of evaluating some JSX instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in line two is that you Declare the ReactDOM but never used it, The ReactDOM is used to display components in the DOM, instead, you just console log the block of code you got so you will be getting a Js object as shown below, what I would give you to fix this is either you change your code to the block of code at the bottom, or you leave it as is and try to get rid of the (import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'(but in this case, you will get a JavaScript Object). [The Js object returned if you want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh7wZ.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
function Element (){
return(
<h1>Hello world</h1>
)
}
ReactDOM.render(<Element />,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Hopefully that helps <3